# How to get connection to postgresql for set up some extensions

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, psql

I try to enable an extension called PostGIS on the database-end. This extension will be in charge to handle all the geospatial storage and requests. I typed this commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE usersDB;
CREATE USER san WITH PASSWORD 'pa$$word';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE usersDB TO san;
LTER ROLE san SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE san SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE san SET timezone TO 'UTC';
```

And then i need to set up extensions but first i need to connect to my database and i type next commands:
psql -h [database_hostname] -p 8000 -U san -l
After that i get an Error like this:
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "san"

I tried to make another user and simple password but the issue is the same!

Comment: 1) This `-p 8000` does not look a Postgres port. Are you sure you are connecting to correct server? 2) Is this `LTER ROLE san SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';` a typo? If not your commands will fail at that point. 3) To question add Postgres version and client(and it's version) being used. 4) Also add content of `pg_hba.conf` for the server to your question. 5) How are you logging to run the commands?

Comment: You right my port is wrong. I write the 5432 down and everything start work!) Thank you!